# sort -n doesn't work?

Tags: sort

I am doing a usual thing that I `sort -n` but this time it does not work for the following input list, partially like

```
./firedock-output_308.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 54.06
./firedock-output_286.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 17.91
./firedock-output_26.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 18.86
./firedock-output_7.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 24.29
./firedock-output_843.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 17.88
./firedock-output_115.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 142.42
```

and the output after `sort -k1,1n` is

```
./firedock-output_1000.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 95.86
./firedock-output_100.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 12.62
./firedock-output_101.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 33.89
./firedock-output_102.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 19.83
./firedock-output_103.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 19.69
./firedock-output_104.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 69.43
./firedock-output_105.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 25.11
./firedock-output_106.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 17.46
./firedock-output_107.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 41.77
./firedock-output_108.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 12.61
./firedock-output_109.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 72.75
./firedock-output_10.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 67.79
./firedock-output_110.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 13.87
./firedock-output_111.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 18.44
./firedock-output_112.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 27.03
./firedock-output_113.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 37.43
./firedock-output_114.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 18.57
./firedock-output_115.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 142.42
./firedock-output_116.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 57.75
./firedock-output_117.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 21.21
```

Why `sort -n` does not work as it normally does (i.e. sort according to numerical order) for this case?

What I want is

```
./firedock-output_1.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 12.62
./firedock-output_2.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 12.62
./firedock-output_3.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 12.62
./firedock-output_4.ref_clashscore_cat_elmo1-NT_rhog1_clashscore:clashscore = 12.62
```

until 1000 (totally there are 1000 lines).

Thanks.

Comment: Try `sort -V`. From man "natural sort of (version) numbers within text"

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved. I need to specify the position of sort key, which is the 19th character.

```
sort -n -k1.19
```

Thanks a lot!